# Source to learn/understand one-shot learning

Tags: one-shot-learning

I'm currently looking into **one-shot learning** and I wonder if there are any good sources/tutorials out there, which demonstrate one-shot learning in a (more or less) "hands-on" way?

Also some hints to **indroductory literature** to one-shot learning would be highly welcome! Are there any books which cover the topic?

I'm not interested in standard ML homepages which pop up on the first page of a Google search. I'm looking for recommendations of people who are somewhat familiar with the topic. So what are the best (serious) sources to start with one-shot learning? *[Maybe like "Barto/Sutton: Reinforcement Learning" or "Hastie et al.: Elements of Stat. Learning"]*

I would be happy for helpful recommendations!

Comment: I think low shot learning is not as matured as reinforcement learning or recurrent networks. So I don't think you'll find any dedicated book on this topic. 

I'm also working in this field and I get all my references and updates from research paper itself. Here is one such list :

https://github.com/e-271/awesome-few-shot-learning